# Load data in Group Detail page in Metro style app

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I have recently started working on metro style apps. I have created a blank project and add a page based on Group Detail Template. I want to use this template as there is a list of items and I want to preview the first item by default and  when I click on a item from the list on the left then I should see preview on the right panel. I created a collection of items and able to show the list by writing below code but I am not able to show the preview .

```
StoreData storeData = new StoreData();
  await storeData.StoreDataAsync();            
  this.DefaultViewModel["Items"] = storeData.Collection;
```

Do I need to write more code to show the preview in right panel??
Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Try taking a look at how one of the other project templates does it.  The blank app template is missing a lot of stuff you need to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    this.DefaultViewModel["Group"] = group;
    this.DefaultViewModel["Items"] = group.Items;

    /// <summary>
    /// Invoked when an item is clicked.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">The GridView (or ListView when the application is snapped)
    /// displaying the item clicked.</param>
    /// <param name="e">Event data that describes the item clicked.</param>
    void ItemView_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        // Navigate to the appropriate destination page, configuring the new page
        // by passing required information as a navigation parameter
        var itemId = ((ItemBase)e.ClickedItem).UniqueId;
        this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(ItemDetailPage), itemId);
    }
```

You will need to make sure your click event handler is hooked up.  To do so add this:

```
ItemClick="ItemView_ItemClick"
```

To any listcontrol which has your items in it.